# Google calendar - login without prompt

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have to do a PHP batch application (so without data prompt) to access to a specified google account and see the calendar.

I see OAuth 2.0 system and I can't find how can I get an authorization without a prompt...so is possibile to read a calendar without an authorization in interface?

thanks

Comment: There's a way to do this, I think in Google Apps they are called service apps?

Comment: Is it your account you are trying to access or someone elses?

Comment: I can't set an app because it's not mine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer could be service accounts. Please take a look here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts#use_service_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts and here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation